# Can you reference external data that can then be used in a driver?

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I was going to LibreOffice Calc to hold the data and try to have the data in one cell go into one empty and then use that to influence a driver. It also needs to be able to be live.
I am a novice in both blender and coding. So this is probably a very simple script.

Comment: It's not a very simple script because you need to write scripts to treat Calc and Blender as a client/server pair and have events in Calc generate messages that are sent to Blender over a network connection where Blender uses them to update the driver's values.

Comment: i tried asking a question on how to broadcast messages using python in LibreOffice but unfortunately no response. https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-can-i-broadcast-a-message-using-python-whenever-i-make-a-cell-change/79138